# When releasing an app on Google Play, do testers who upgrade from an alpha or beta version, count as a new install?

Tags: android, google-play

I need to know if beta testers upgrading from an ALPHA or BETA version to a Production version, when releasing an app, will have an impact on whether or not the app will become a Trending/Top New.

This will help me determine how many testers I should invite when releasing a beta version.